# INSERT IGNORE equivalent for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, bulkinsert

Is it possible not to reindex document again, if there is a document with this `_id` already? Maybe something like `INSERT IGNORE` query in MySQL?

I use bulk API, and it takes to long to reindex again, so I just want to index missing documents.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you use the create action instead of index?

the create action fails if the document already exists.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: Thanks! How could I miss this? )

Comment: your post answers my question, so I mark it as accepted) However `create` operation appears to be several times slower than `index`. Do you know a better alternative by chance? )

Comment: an alternativ could be to use the index action with versioning and then decide if you want to use internal or external versioning in elasticsearch


https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-versioning

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give it a try

Comment: When they say it "fails", does it mean there is an exception that needs to be caught? Because I got version conflicts back.